# Somar vários campos de uma mesma tabela na mesma query

Tags: query, informix

Tenho uma tabela "X" com vários campos e um dos campos é "data" e o outro é "tipo".

Na mesma query preciso retornar o seguinte:
- Numero de registos em Abril
- Numero de registos em Abril com o tipo 1
- Numero de registos em Abril com o tipo 2
- Numero de registos em Março
- Numero de registos em Março com o tipo 1
- Numero de registos em Março com o tipo 2

Só preciso de registos de Abril e Maio.

Tentei utilizar o COUNT com o IF (como no MySql) mas não funcionou.

Comment: Usa o `CASE` , seria uma solução similar a sugerida pelo @CesarMiguel , porém sem usar subselect... Para saber como usar o CASE , pesquisa no [IBM Knowledge Center](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.welcome.doc/welcome.htm). (nesta pagina da IBM , mude a língua para o inglês, antes de pesquisar, ela em português não funciona direito)

Comment: @FilipeMoraes a resposta resolveu a tua questão?

Comment: @CesarMiguel sim, mas utilizei o CASE no lugar de vários selects, como o ceinmart informou no comentário acima. Consegue alterar a reposta utilizando CASE para marca-la como certa?

Comment: @FilipeMoraes, consigo, mas agora estou com pouco tempo. Depois aviso quando editar

Comment: @FilipeMoraes, já acrescentei. Vê o que achas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podes fazer vários `SELECT` para o resultado pretendido:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM tbl_x WHERE MONTH(dataCriacao) = 4) AS Numero_registos_Abril,
    (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM tbl_x WHERE MONTH(dataCriacao) = 4 AND tipo = 1) AS Numero_registos_Abril_tipo1,
    (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM tbl_x WHERE MONTH(dataCriacao) = 4 AND tipo = 2) AS Numero_registos_Abril_tipo2,
    (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM tbl_x WHERE MONTH(dataCriacao) = 3) AS Numero_registos_Marco,
    (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM tbl_x WHERE MONTH(dataCriacao) = 3 AND tipo = 1) AS Numero_registos_Marco_tipo1,
    (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM tbl_x WHERE MONTH(dataCriacao) = 3 AND tipo = 2) AS Numero_registos_Marco_tipo2,
FROM tbl_x
```

**EDIT:**

Utilizando o `CASE`, e de forma similar aos vários `select` da solução acima, irás fazer um `COUNT` para cada uma das tuas condições:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(dataCriacao) = 4 THEN 1 END) AS Numero_registos_Abril,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(dataCriacao) = 4 AND tipo = 1 THEN 1 END) AS Numero_registos_Abril_tipo1,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(dataCriacao) = 4 AND tipo = 2 THEN 1 END) AS Numero_registos_Abril_tipo2,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(dataCriacao) = 3 THEN 1 END) AS Numero_registos_Marco,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(dataCriacao) = 3 AND tipo = 1 THEN 1 END) AS Numero_registos_Marco_tipo1,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(dataCriacao) = 3 AND tipo = 2 THEN 1 END) AS Numero_registos_Marco_tipo2,
FROM tbl_x
```

Neste exemplo, o valor que colocas no `THEN` é irrelevante.